# Time complexity and number of elements operated on

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Algorithm  A executes an operation of time complexity O(log n) on an array storing n elements.

Algorithm B chooses log n elements from an array, and performs an O(n) calculation on each.

Since d(n) = O(f(n)) and e(n) = O(g(n)), then d(n)*e(n) = O(f(n)*g(n)), does that mean that algorithms A and B both have a time complexity of O(n log n)?

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm A has a time complexity of O(log n) and the algorithm B has a time complexity of O(n * log n). Algorithm B calculates something with O(n) on log * n elements. I assume that choosing is equivalent to sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that B doesn't take too long to choose the elements, and you meant Algorithm A does O(log n) work on *each* element, yes.